# Error While publishing infopath form to Sharepoint

Tags: infopath

There is portal which is hosted in Office 365. I needed to do modifications on that portal.

I opened a list and clicked on the "Customize form" button to open the form in Infopath Designer 2010. Then I did some modifications on it.

When I am trying to publish the form into SharePoint list I am getting the error message like below.

> The Publish operation could not be completed.It cannot be determined
>   if the form templete was successfully published.Try publishing the
>   form template again, or change the list settings to use the default
>   Sharepoint form. The SOAP response indicates that an error occured on
>   the server Server was unable to process request----> Owners cannot add
>   an item.

Can anyone please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem. What access do you have to the site collection, site and list?

Comment: I am having administrator privileges.